Popover does not appear when a button is tapped inside a List section
Popover functionality breaks when enabled for multiple section buttons, but works as intended when limited to one.
struct ContentView: View {

var items = ["Note 1", "Note 2", "Note 3"]

@State private var showPopover = false

var body: some View {
    List {
        Section {
            ForEach(items, id: \.self) { item in
                VStack {
                    Text(item)
                        .padding()
                    Button(action: {
                        showPopover.toggle()
                    }, label: {
                        Text("Notes")
                    })
                    .popover(isPresented: $showPopover) {
                        Text(item)
                            .padding()
                            .foregroundStyle(Color.red)
                            .font(.body)
                            .lineLimit(nil)
                            .presentationCompactAdaptation(.popover)
                    }
                }
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Although each section is intended to display notes via popovers, SwiftUI appears to have limitations in handling this functionality across multiple sections.

What exactly do you mean by "breaks"? What does "works as intended when limited to one" mean? Can you show a code snippet that is "limited to one"?

popovers fail to display when multiple buttons within a List section are configured to trigger them, but work as expected when only one button per section is enabled. For example in above code snippet if I add following condition -> if item ==  "Note 2" {Button{}} it will work fine as only one button is added.

\.self isn't a valid id keypath
